# Styling Twitter Bootstrap Modal Close Icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, rounded-corners

I'm trying to do some styling on Twitter Bootstrap modal close icon. This is the CSS I'm using:

```
.modal-header .close {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -30px !important;
    margin-top: -30px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

It works pretty good on Chrome / IE, however sometimes on Firefox I get strange behavior (image is attached). Is there additional CSS rule that I have to supply to have this work on Firefox as well?

[image]

Comment: reproduce your problem using jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proved to be an issue with graphic card(s) on several laptop(s) that were using Intel graphics. Funny thing is that only Firefox was susceptible to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of firefox you may need to add `-moz-border-radius: 15px`