# Change color of close button in bootstrap modal window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using modal window with boostrap. I've already changed the background and font color, but I did not succed changing the upper right close button to white.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true" class="modal_button">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
```

Here's my css attribute

```
.modal-header {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #261f31;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I would like to turn the X button in white

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Bootstrap is setting the color like this:

```
.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  opacity: .2;
}
```

So you can override it with this:

```
.close {
    color: #fff; 
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Had to override opacity too. `.close {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: check the **stylish close button** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556772/styling-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close-icon) in the question, hope helps someone.

Comment: You actually need to set the color for the span and the opacity for the button.  `.close{opacity: 1} .close span{color: #fff}`

Comment: For [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/close-button/#white-variant) you need to add the `btn-close-white` class. This sets the `filter: invert(1) grayscale(100%) brightness(200%)`

Answer (score 20):

In bootstrap 5 they have a class that allows you to change the color to white for the close button.

`<button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" aria-label="Close"></button>`

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 7):

Just Write Down The Code

```
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```

Comment: Estoy agregando modo oscuro a una aplicación web, me función exactamente como necesitaba

Comment: This is exactly what adding the btn-close-white class would do anyway, so it provides the exact same effect if you can't use that for what ever reason.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way you can override the defual x button in modal popup

```
  button.close {
        background: #d73e4d;
        background: rgba(215, 62, 77, 0.75);
        border: 0 none !important;
        color: #fff7cc;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        font-size: 34px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 1;
        margin: 0px 1px;
        opacity: 1;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: none;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 46px;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 5 you need to add the btn-close-white class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).